# Mercurial push fails with `abort: error: ''`

Tags: mercurial

I'm pushing to a Bitbucket HG repo. The push started failing after I enabled the rebase extension in my `.hg/hgrc` file (which is probably not related)

I'm using HG version 2.8.2

The error (from `hg push --debug --traceback -v`) is:

```
http auth: user Jorn86, password ******
using auth.bb.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 133, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 806, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 585, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 897, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 868, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 803, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 512, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 4711, in push
    newbranch=opts.get('new_branch'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1866, in push
    bool(inc))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/discovery.py", line 238, in checkheads
    headssum = _headssummary(repo, remote, outgoing)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/discovery.py", line 165, in _headssummary
    remotemap = remote.branchmap()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/wireproto.py", line 115, in plain
    encresref.set(self._submitone(f.func_name, encargsorres))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/wireproto.py", line 163, in _submitone
    return self._call(op, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 171, in _call
    fp = self._callstream(cmd, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 118, in _callstream
    resp = self.urlopener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
    url, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 436, in http_error_auth_reqed
    self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
    response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
    return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 368, in https_open
    return self.do_open(self._makeconnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 257, in do_open
    raise urllib2.URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error ''>
abort: error: ''
```

I've also seen the same trace, but with error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
abort: error: _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

What can I do to push to the repo again?

Comment: These are low-level errors, i.e. what Mercurial prints when something with the underlying connection goes wrong at the protocol level and it can't tell why; it usually (but not always) is a server problem. In my experience, `https` URLs in conjunction with push can be a bit flaky on bitbucket (I just tried and got a couple of error messages, followed by normal behavior at the third attempt), while `ssh` connections are more robust (probably because they don't run through the normal web servers that also have to handle a bunch of other stuff).

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be a problem with the connection to the remote server, in this case Bitbucket. The website itself was also somewhat unresponsive at the time.